# Activar campos automaticamente ante un error en el login

Tags: javascript, html, angular

tengo un pequeño login, usuario y contraseña. Cuando hay un error en el login, eje: contraseña incorrecta, el login se habilita con un click en los campos. Con qué propiedad, atributo, funcionalidad, etc. podría hacer que ante el error quede el cursor listo para escribir denuevo?

```
 <form #f [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="submit()">

      <img id="user" class="user" [src]="photo">

      <div class="messagebox-container">
        <mat-form-field>
          <input 
            matInput 
            formControlName="username"
            type="text" 
            placeholder="Usuario"
            >
          <mat-error *ngIf="loginForm.get('username').hasError('required')">
            Debe ingresar su nombre de usuario
          </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>

      </div>

      <div>
        <mat-form-field>
          <input 
            matInput
            formControlName="password"
            type="password"
            id="password"
            name="password"
            class="form-control"
            placeholder="Password"
            >
          <mat-error *ngIf="loginForm.get('password').hasError('required')">
            Debe ingresar su contraseña
          </mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Hola. Pon el codigo html que utilizas editanto la pregunta por favor.

Comment: @Angel, listo!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu `submit()` ocupas hacer algo como esto:

```js
 submit(model, invalid, event) {

    //Esto es para que se ejecuten las validaciones cuando se presiona el boton
    this.loginForm.markAllAsTouched();
    this.loginForm.updateValueAndValidity();

    //Por si lo ejecutas desde algun otro lado como un evento click. Anula
    // la propagacioin y eventos por default. 
    if (invalid) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      event.preventDefault();

      //Aqui viene lo que te interesa. Recorremos todos los controles
      for (const key of Object.keys(this.loginForm.controls)) {
        //Obtenemos unicamente el primer resultado invalido. 
        if (this.loginForm.controls[key].invalid) {
          // Obtenemos la referencia al elemento nativo con la etiqueta
          // formcontrolname + nombre del campo
          const invalidControl = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector(
            '[formcontrolname="' + key + '"]'
          );
          //Enfocamos el elemento. 
          invalidControl.focus();
          break;
        }
      }
     //Detenemos la ejecucion
     return 
    }
```

Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4iemzk)

> Por fines prácticos no instale material. Debe funcionarte igual.

Comment: a qué hace referencia this.el?

Comment: Es una dependencia inyectada `el:ElementRef`. Esta en el constructor. Sirve para manipular directamente el DOM.

Comment: excelente, gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Deberás acceder al elemento `input` des del *view-controller* para poder llamar a la función *focus* (propiedad de cada *HTML Element*).

Primero, la damos una *id* al elemento `input`

```html
<!-- ... -->
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput placeholder="Usuario" #username>
</mat-form-field>
<!-- ... -->
```

Con la sintaxis `#id` le otorgamos la *id* que queramos. Cabe mencionar que esa *id* es diferente a la del *DOM* (`id="..."`).

Des del controlador, ahora podemos inyectar el elemento.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {

  // Con la directive ViewChild podemos inyectar elementos
  // directamente del HTML. El argumento que le pasamos es el id del elemento
  // Nos devolverá un objeto de tipo ElementRef
  // Opcionalmente podemos decirle de qué tipo es (si lo necesitamos).
  @ViewChild('username') usernameField: ElementRef<MatInput>;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

Por último y con el elemento en el controlador, sólo debemos acceder al `nativeElement` de éste, que nos devolverá el elemento nativo del *DOM* ya renderizado. Por lo que tendremos acceso a todas las funciones de cualquier elemento HTML, entre ellas, la función `focus`.

```
focus = () => {
  this.usernameField.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

Espero que sirva.

Comment: muchas gracias :)