# Hacer foco en el input usuario en un login

Tags: html, angular

Tengo un login con user y password, cuando hay un error por ejemplo de mal usuario o mal contraseña, quiero que me enfoque en el campo, como puedo hacerlo?
, tengo esto:

```
 submit(): void {
    let msg= '';
    const user = this.loginForm.get('username').value;
    const pass = this.loginForm.get('password').value
    this.loading = true;
    if (!(user && pass)) {
      this.loading = false;
      this.snackbar.open('Debe ingresar sus credenciales para ingresar', undefined, { duration: 15000 });
//AQUI HAGO FOCUS Y FUNCIONA      
**
for (const key of Object.keys(this.loginForm.controls)) {
        if (this.loginForm.controls[key].invalid) {
          const invalidControl = this.el.nativeElement.querySelector(
            '[formcontrolname="' + key + '"]'
          );
          invalidControl.focus();
          break;
        }
      }
**
    } else {
      const userProfile$ = this.profileService.getProfileConfig(user);
      const login$ = this.loginService.login(user, pass);

      login$.pipe(
        withLatestFrom(userProfile$),
        first()
      ).subscribe(
        ([login, profile]) => {
          this.loading = false;
          console.log(login);
          login.numberOfResourcesRows = profile.numberRowsResources;
          login.redirectAfterLogin = profile.redirectLink;
          this.loginService.setUser(login);
          this.navigator.goToUserHomePage(login.redirectAfterLogin);
        },
        error => {
          this.loading=false;
          switch (error.status) {
            case 511: msg = 'Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos';
                      break;       
          }
          this.snackbar.open(msg, undefined, {duration: 15000});
//AQUI HE PROBADO METER EL FOCUS Y NO FUNCIONA
```

He probado realizar foco en las partes donde puse anotaciones en mayuscula, en una funciona y en otra no.
Alguien sabría decirme por qué es así? qué estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Posible [duplicado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/355905/activar-campos-automaticamente-ante-un-error-en-el-login)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Activar campos automaticamente ante un error en el login](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/355905/activar-campos-automaticamente-ante-un-error-en-el-login)

Comment: hola, no en este caso